# "command multencode is unrecognized" despite having installed multencode?

Tags: stata

I'm executing a Stata DoFile.

When the execution reaches the following line:

```
#delimit ;
multencode bl_qc2p77_goods_1 bl_qc2p77_goods_2 bl_qc2p77_goods_3 bl_qc2p77_goods_4 
bl_qc2p77_goods_5 bl_qc2p77_goods_6 bl_qc2p77_goods_7 bl_qc2p77_goods_8, gen(num1 num2
num3 num4 num5 num6 num7 num8);
#delimit cr
```

I get the following error message:

> command **multencode** is not recognized

To install `multencode`, I ran `ssc install multencode` before executing the DoFile. In fact, when I did so, I got the following message:

> file c:\ado\plus\next.trk already exists

This seems to suggest that `multencode` was already installed, however when I ran `ado`, `multencode` did not appear.

I'm new to Stata, does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `ssc install multencode, replace`

Comment: The message implies only that Stata is confused about documentation of installation of community-contributed packages. This may arise sometimes if people install in non-standard ways, but there is no telling what is up in your case. Don’t worry about it. As @Wouter signals, you should install directly. The only sure signal that you have installed something is Stata being able to see the files, which should be in whatever Stata calls PLUS. See help for adopath and sysdir commands.